# 'Module' Object Has no Attribute 'models'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new in python.
consider this code:

```
from django.db import models


class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()


class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()


class Book(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher)
    publication_date = models.DateField()
```

and this is my project structure:

[image]

Why i get this error when to want validating ?

```
'Module' Object Has no Attribute 'models'


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 4.0.1\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 41, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 182, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/Users/Shahr_000/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/Users/Shahr_000/PycharmProjects/HelloWorld\HelloWorld\books\models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Publisher(models.Model):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Model'
```

Comment: Are you have `Model` in models.py ? maybe you have a typo here ? ( note about upper case and lowers too) (case sensitive)

Comment: How did you end up with that project structure? That's not been the way to do things since at least version 1.4, and it's not the structure that the `startproject` or `startapp` commands will create for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I create manually

Comment: Well, don't. The recommended structure is recommended for a good reason.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I create again with startapp but i get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy pasted your code.Worked for me.You should delete your migrations and try again.

cheers :-)